# I'm new with ubuntu and I made a misstake in system settings

Tags: 14.10

While I'm exploring the system settings, I made the touchpad "off", and Ican't move the mouse any more.How can I make it "on" again??

Comment: synclient TouchpadOff=0

@Asma Sarhan, This will enable the touchpad. Run this from terminal

Answer (score 0):

To enable/disable touch-pad using the command line in Ubuntu.

It’s very easy, just open terminal from the dash or use key combination Ctrl+Alt+T

Then to disable the touchpad run the command

```
synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

To re-enable the touchpad

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

This will enabled the touch-pad back.